# Solving a system of linear equations with unspecified coefficients...Was: Inverse of a matrix with coefficient

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following matrix 
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
 -(k_1 + k_6)& k_2 & k_5 \\
k_1 & -(k_2+k_3) & k_4 \\
k_6 & k_3 & -(k_4+k_5)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where all the parameters $k_j$, $j\in\{1, ..., 6\}$ are positive real numbers. Now if we want to solve the matrix-vector equation $Ax=0$ for $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix}$, how do we do so? I know that $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(0,0,0)$ solves it but what other solutions are there and how do we get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write this linear systems of equations as augmented coefficient matrix:
\begin{align}
\left(\begin{array}{c c c | c}
 -(k_1 + k_6)& k_2 & k_5 & x_1\\
k_1 & -(k_2+k_3) & k_4 & x_2 \\
k_6 & k_3 & -(k_4+k_5) & x_3
\end{array}\right)
& = \left(\begin{array}{c c c | c}
k_1 & -(k_2+k_3) & k_4 & x_2 \\
k_6 & k_3 & -(k_4+k_5) & x_3 \\
 -(k_1 + k_6)& k_2 & k_5 & x_1\\
\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
Now, by adding rows I and II onto the third column you get
\begin{align}
\left(\begin{array}{c c c | c}
k_1 & -(k_2+k_3) & k_4 & x_2 \\
k_6 & k_3 & -(k_4+k_5) & x_3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & x_1 + x_2 + x_3\\
\end{array}\right) \\
\end{align}
Here you can see that the matrix doesn't have full rank (either 1 or 2) and is therefore not invertible, as @Bernard pointed out.
You can also see, that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3$ will have to be zero for this system to have a solution.

Now, subtract $\frac{k_6}{k_1}\cdot$I from the second to obtain
\begin{align}
\left(\begin{array}{c c c | c}
k_1 & -(k_2+k_3) & k_4 & x_2 \\
0 & k_2 + \frac{k_6}{k_1}(k_2 + k_3) & -(k_5 + \frac{k_6}{k_1} k_4) & x_3 + \frac{x_2(k_1 - k_6)}{k_6} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \\
\end{array}\right) \\
\end{align}
Can you take it from here?
To check your solutions, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%20((-(a%20%2B%20f),%20b,%20e),%20(a,%20-(b%2Bc),%20d),(f,%20c,%20-(d%2Be)))%20((x),(y),(z))%20%3D%20((0),(0),(0))).